# Is it possible to create a application gateway without backend address pool in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm-template, azure-application-gateway

While creation of azure application gateway using ARM template is it possible to create a application gateway without backend address pool, request routing rules, health probes and listeners.

If so what is the possible method to do so using ARM template?

Is the creation of application gateway without using backend pool possible using powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, but it wont do anything.